# can i do simple addition using firebase values?

Tags: java, android, firebase, counter

hi guys i have a database tree in firebase. Which im using for a download counter for each section of my app. as each user downloads an app it increments the value for that user by one.

each user has its own branch for each app. is there a way to get my app or firebase to add the values of each user before displaying it in my stats section.

ie if mark has downloaded 2 apps and steve has downloaded 4 the values would need to be added and then displayed in my text view which at the moment says null apps downloaded.

hope you guys can help as its frying my head. thanks

Comment: For the things such as incremental counters, you can use firebase transaction https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions

Comment: The above looks like a very promising link.

Comment: thanks very much guys will look in to this